# ng-repeat: How to show and hide the div that is in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

While working on ng-repeat I had encountered with some problems. I am adding a multiple menus and items for my application. when I am clicking additems button on the HTML it have to show only items(to add items to menu) div but unfortunately it was happened like this i have 2 menus example veg, non-veg for that I have to add items like chicken pizza for non-veg etc. and some fruits to veg menu.
I felt there is some condition to be used to show and hide the div in mg-repeat.

can any please solve my problem 
thanks,
In advance.

### In HTML

```
<div ng-init="getMenus()"><div ng-show="restaurants"><div ng-repeat="value in restaurants track by $index"><div ng-repeat="menu in value.menus track by $index"><div><h3><b>Menu Name :{{menu.title}}</b></h3></div><br><div class="settings-heading col-md-offset-2" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;"ng-show="ui.showDiv" ><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name" style="margin-bottom:10px;" ng-model="itemname" autocomplete="on"><div  style="float:right;"> <input type="submit" class="btn  btn-next" value="Save" style="font-weight: 600;"ng-click="addItems()"> </div</div><br><div><button  class='btn  btn-next col-md-offset-2' style='font-weight: 600;'  ng-click="ui.showDiv =!ui.showDiv">Add items to {{menu.title}}</button</div><br><div ng-repeat="value in restaurants track by $index"><div ng-repeat="menu in value.menus track by $index"><div ng-repeat="test in menu.items track by $index"><div class="settings-heading col-md-offset-2"><h3><b>Item Name :{{test.itemTitle}}</b></h3></div><br></div></div></div></div></div></div</div>
```

### in controller

```
$scope.addItems = function(){
$scope.ui = { showDiv: false ,showDiv2: true };}
```

Comment: why have you included a minified version?

Comment: i just need to hide and show only the div which i have clicked. there is no much logic in that. it is working without ng-repeat.

Comment: Please prettify your html to let it be readable

Comment: you can use data-ng-if

Comment: we are not robots here, so we are not good at reading minified code. well, most of us

Comment: and of curse you have unclosed tags fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add ng-hide conditionally too

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-hide="isHidden($index)" ng-click="hideThis($index)">
  {{item}}
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['Jhon', 'Jason', 'Judy', 1,2,3,4,5,6,67,8,9];
    $scope.hiddenValues = []
    $scope.hideThis = function(i) {
       $scope.hiddenValues.push(i)
    }

    $scope.isHidden = function(i)  {
    return $scope.hiddenValues.indexOf(i) > -1
    }
}
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rt14Lyma/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use data ng if

for example
check this plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/0YGCN4lLU6otixortG9l?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="n in nums">
    <p data-ng-if="n % 2==0">{{n}}</p>
</div>
```

will show only the numbers that divide by 2

and this is the array

```
$scope.nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

much easier and very simple
if you fix your code will show you how to do it in your code
you can also do it by function that return true or false
and also you can do the same with data ng show or hide